# array_diff_assoc() argument #1 is not an array php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

So I have this object:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"create-users",
        "display_name":"Create user",
        "description":"Add new user"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"edit-user",
        "display_name":"Edit user",
        "description":"Edit existing user"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"create-post",
        "display_name":"Create post",
        "description":"create new post"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name":"edit-post",
        "display_name":"Edit post",
        "description":"edit existing post"
    }
]
```

and this other one:

```
[
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"create-post",
        "display_name":"Create post",
        "description":"create new post"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name":"edit-post",
        "display_name":"Edit post",
        "description":"edit existing post"
    }
]
```

Now I am looping through these two objects in nested foreach loops top compare which of the arrays from the two objects are equal(equal key and value pairs).

Here are the foreach loops:

```
foreach ($role_perms as $role_perm) {
    foreach ($all_perms as $all_perm) {
        if (array_diff_assoc($all_perm, $role_perm)) {
            $all_perm['check'] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But I have no idea why I keep getting the error

> array_diff_assoc(): Argument #1 is not an array 
>   (on the line of code with the if statement.)

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any help

Comment: `var_dump($all_perm, $role_perm);`

Comment: You confuse "array" and "object".

Comment: @arkascha please can you clarify me on this. The first two i refered to as objects, I thought they were objects containing arrays? Is that where I confuse it?

Comment: The code you posted is each a numerically indexed array holding a few objects. Each of those objects obviously contains some named properties. You want to find out the class of the objects, that will allow easier usage compared to generic handling.

Comment: You posted some PHP code and some JSON data which, btw, is Javascript. You didn't post how do you decode the JSONs into PHP data structures. Take a look at the documentation of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), use it correctly (i.e. pass `TRUE` as its second argument) and the error will vanish.

Answer (score 1):

array_diff_assoc() is for comparing arrays. And your data is not.

If you want to use array_diff_assoc() modify your data structure so that you have an array of arrays. For instance:

```
$your_array = [
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "name"=>"create-post",
        "display_name"=>"Create post",
        "description"=>"create new post"
    ],
    [
        "id"=>4,
        "name"=>"edit-post",
        "display_name"=>"Edit post",
        "description"=>"edit existing post"
    ]
];
```

**Edited:**
As a workaround, cast objects to arrays in case you can't modify your data structure.

```
   $object = new stdClass();
   $object->a = 'AAA';
   $object->b = 'BBB';

   var_dump((array) $object);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { ["a"]=> string(3) "AAA" ["b"]=> string(3) "BBB" }
```

In your case:

```
foreach ($role_perms as $role_perm) {
    foreach ($all_perms as $all_perm) {
        if (array_diff_assoc((array) $all_perm, (array) $role_perm)) {
            $all_perm['check'] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify well enough. The data I provided was manually written by me but its actually records from the database. Does it mean values returned from the database are not of type array? Sorry again this may not make sense cause I am a beginner in php?

Comment: In case you can't modify your original data structure, as a workaround you can cast objects to array prior to use array_diff_assoc(). I add an example to my answer.